# Make Bootstrap columns to take 100% of the row width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I think it is something simple, but as i'm new to bootstrap I don't know how to do it, I searched and didn't find anything about it.

I want the columns to take 100% the width of the row, I marked the row with a red border in the example below.

I know it's the padding of the columns that give this spacing but I have not figured out a way to remove the padding keeping the spacing between the columns and making them fill the row.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2sj2nbL/1/)

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px;border-right: 1px solid red;border-left: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your class from `container` to `container-fluid`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
...
</div>
```

More about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Comment: container-fluid expand the row to 100% of the viewport width, that's not what i want

Answer (score 1):

remove class "container.  and then try you will get full width row.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the space between columns in you row, in bootstrap 4, you can use `no-gutters` like this:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This
nest row inside row

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-*-*">
      <div class="products">
        .......
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Link For reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/w3tkqt68/1/)

hope this helps..

Comment: It worked, except for internet explorer, do you know what it can be?

Comment: @GabrielSouza What is the issue in IE?

Answer (score -1):

you should use **100%** of all div width if problem solved well and good otherwise you can use **left** and **right** margins in (-) minus.

Comment: What do you mean by "use 100% of all div width"?